# publishing an android library on Bitbucket as a maven artifact issues

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bitbucket, pom.xml

I'm trying to publish an Android library as a Maven artifact on a Bitbucket repository using [this article](https://medium.com/@Mul0w/publish-with-gradle-on-bitbucket-1463236dc460#.jz7ljgit2)

it's my First work, please explain Simple and Clearly
what is **`POM`** , **`wagon-git`** and **`deployerJar`** and finaly how can I fix this error :

I get this **ERROR** :

> Error:Could not find method deployerJar() for arguments [ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.3] 
>       on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

my **Project level** `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my **app level**(library) `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}

apply from: 'uploadArchives.gradle'
```

and the created `uploadArchives.gradle` file in the library madule :

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
    deployerJar
}

dependencies {
    deployerJar "ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.3"
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = "com.example"
        pom.artifactId = "myLibraryName"
        pom.version = "1.0"
        configuration = configurations.deployerJar
        repository(url: "git:master://git@bitbucket.org:myTeam/myLibraryName.git"){
            authentication(userName: "my_bitbucket_username", password: "my_bitbucket_password")
        }
        pom.project {
            name "myLibraryName"
            packaging "aar" //POM_PACKAGING
            description "Some Description"
            url "https://bitbucket.org/myTeam/myLibraryName"
            scm {
                url "https://bitbucket.org/myTeam/myLibraryName"
                connection "https://my_bitbucket_username@bitbucket.org/myTeam/myLibraryName.git"
                developerConnection "https://my_bitbucket_username@bitbucket.org/myTeam/myLibraryName.git"
            }
            licenses {
                license {
                    name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
                    url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
                    distribution "myLibraryName"
                }
            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    id "my_bitbucket_username"
                    name "my_bitbucket_name"
                    email "my_email"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution

I remove all `build.gradle`s impurity except `apply from: 'uploadArchives.gradle'`

and move `uploadArchives` {object} 's values into `gradle.properties` like this:

```
GROUP=com.example
```

and use like this :

```
uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = GROUP
        ...
    }
}
```

and add this at the end of `uploadArchies.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post an update with all the three gradle files after your last edits? I followed the same article but i can't find a solution that works for me.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

POM is short of **Project Object Model**, is the fundamental unit of work in Maven.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

`wagon-git` is the name of artifact having group ID `ar.com.synergian`

As i know there is no scope of the name of `deployerJar`

Comment: Thank you, but why we must use `wagon-git` and why I get `deployerJar` Error ?

Comment: wagon-git, enables deploying artifacts in remote Git SCM repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I run in same issue with step-by-step instruction from article, that wagon repository is linking as on instruction. 
For making things working all you need to do in original file is just replace ordering of `configurations` and `dependencies` sections. The `configurations` should go first. In your example this also cause similar flow as you declare using of this configuration before it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with the new Bitbucket API 2.0.
I'm using now:

```
repository(url: 'git:releases://https://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@bitbucket.org/' + COMPANY + '/' + REPOSITORY_NAME + '.git')
```

instead of

```
repository(url: "git:master://git@bitbucket.org:myTeam/myLibraryName.git"){
    authentication(userName: "my_bitbucket_username", password: "my_bitbucket_password")
}
```

and it works well!